# Is $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ a semisimple Lie group?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, semisimple-lie-algebras

I am learning Hyperbolic Geometry. Few days ago I attended a seminar on hyperbolic geometry.

The professor introduced us with Teichmüller space and later he presented Teichmüller space is as a representation space for surface groups into $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ (the group is known as the isometry group of the Poincare half-plane model of the hyperbolic plane). Later, he told that a natural generalization is to consider surface group representations in other semisimple Lie groups.

My question is as follows: Is $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ a semisimple Lie group?

Comment: The Lie algebra is semisimple, because its Killing form is nondegenerate. Hence $PSL_2(\Bbb R)$ is a semisimple Lie group - see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Lie_group).

Comment: Do you know the definition of a semisimple Lie group? Did you try to apply it in the case of $PSL(2,R)$ and where did you get stuck? On the more basic level: Do you know how to equip $PSL(2,R)$ with a Lie group structure?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Sir, I don't Lie groups and algebra. But I want to learn it after completing my differential geometry course work. I attended one seminar on hyperbolic geometry recently, which motivates to study representation space of surface groups and if we change PSL(2,R) with any semi-simple Lie group of higher rank. So, I asked the question.

Comment: Then you are not ready for this question. You should either first learn some Lie theory or ignore semisimple Lie groups and focus on hyperbolic geometry.